# Saving grep results to a file on a remote box

Tags: linux, grep

I'm somewhat new in Linux. I have to read logs on a remote host and save certain lines, found with grep command to a file. The problem is that I don't have permissions to create a file on the host. Is there a workaround the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run something like the following:

```
ssh remotehost "grep certainline logs*" > file
```

to save the file locally.

Otherwise, you might be able to create a file in `/tmp`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention but I'm going to assume you're using ssh to access the remote machine.  So you can run the command on the remote machine and redirect the output on the local machine like so:

```
ssh remotehost 'grep pattern /var/log/mylog' > mylocalfile
```

Note that the redirection occurs outside the quoted command that is given to ssh to send to the remote host.  If you were to put it inside the quotes then the redirection would occur on the remote side.